# Pattern Troubles

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java pattern I would like to match.  I want to take my initial pattern an match the first occurrence of it.  However, I consider

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String expression = "(\\s*(a{1}\\s*b{1})\\s*)";

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(" ab");
        //should be rejected
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner("cab");

        System.out.println(scanner1.findWithinHorizon(expression, 0));
        System.out.println(scanner2.findWithinHorizon(expression, 0));
    }
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
ab
ab
```

I've tried modifying the pattern to use reluctant and possessive quantifiers, but neither seem to produce the results I expect.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `{1}` is redundant: they can be safely omitted.

Comment: @Bart Kiers Thanks for the tip.  I'm still a little new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to only match " ab" and not "cab" or "c ab", so use this regex to start at the beginning of the string: `final String expression = "^(\\s*(a{1}\\s*b{1})\\s*)";`

If you want to also match "c ab" but not "cab" try this: `final String expression = "((?<!\\w)\\s*(a{1}\\s*b{1})\\s*)";`

Comment: Well I think the first one did exactly what I wanted it to do, but could you please explain how it works?  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: It's basically your expression with the additional ^ character in front which means the match must start at the beginning of the string. Thus if the string starts with anything but whitespace or 'a' it won't match.  The second expression just says that there must not be any word character directly before the first 'a'.

Comment: A quite good site on regular expressions can be found here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Think about that `(?<!\\w)+` for a minute: why would you ever need to match `(?<!\w)` more than once in the same spot?  (Or, in the case of `*` or `?`, why would you want to make it optional?)  Many regex flavors treat it as a syntax exception when you tack a quantifier onto a zero-width assertion; I think Java should, too, but it just ignores the quantifier.

Comment: @Alan, yes you could just drop that `+`. I'll update the answer.