# Pattern Parsing Java

Tags: java, regex

Pretend my goal in a program is to parse as many occurrences of `"ab"` out of a string as I can.  I approach this problem with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String expression = "^(\\s*ab)";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("ab abab  ab");

    while (scanner.hasNext())
    {
        String next = scanner.findWithinHorizon(expression, 0);

        if (next == null)
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(next);
        }
    }
}
```

The caret at the beginning of the expression is to disallow anything but whitespace at the beginning of each read as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675785/pattern-troubles).  It's there to prevent something like `"cab"` or `"c ab"` from being allowed.  In fact, I would expect null to be returned and FAIL to be printed to the console if one of these two cases occur.  If I remove the caret from the expression, it works perfectly fine on input such as `"ab abab  ab"`, but fails to return null for `"c ab"`.  On the other hand, if I leave the caret, then `"c ab"` returns null as expected but `"ab abab  ab"` fails.  How can I make this work?

**Edit**

My original post may have been a little vague.  The example I gave above is a simpler version of my real problem.  the pattern `ab` is a filler pattern I would replace with something more interesting, say an email address regex or a hexadecimal value.

In my application, the input to the scanner is not a string, but an input stream of which I have no knowledge.  My goal in the loop is to read in values one at a time from the input and verify their contents match some pattern.  If they do, then I could do something more interesting with them.  If not, then the program terminates.

In the above example, I would expect an input of ab abab  ab to output:

```
ab
 ab
ab
  ab
```

I would expect `c ab` to output:

```
FAIL
```

and I would expect `ab cab` to output:

```
ab
FAIL
```

Comment: Your goal is a little confusing. If you want to parse occurrences of "ab", then why is "c ab" not right? It is an occurrence. Are you saying that you want a String that only has those 2 characters in it?

Comment: could you please clarify the criteria for matching and provide some sample strings with expected outputs? You mention that you want to parse as many occurrences of 'ab' out of a string, but then you say that 'cab' and 'c ab' should not match. Should the string contain only the letter combination 'ab'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the other thread you wanted to match the first occurence of `ab` so the caret was fine. 
If you want to match every occurence of `ab` until another character occurs, try this expression: `String expression = "\\G(\\s*ab)";`

The `\G` means that the next match should start at the position the previous stopped at.

If I use that with your code I get the following results:

1. Input = "ab abab  ab" , Output = "ab", " ab", "ab", "  ab"
2. Input = "**c**ab abab  ab", Output = "FAIL"
3. Input = "ab **c** abab  ab", Output = "ab", "FAIL"
4. Input = "ab abab  ab**c**", Output = "ab", " ab", "ab", "  ab", "FAIL"

Comment: That's pretty cool Thomas.  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks again.

Comment: More info in the Javadoc of the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class

Answer (score 0):

Well...
I think you may do this with one call of regex

Try the following pattern:

```
expression = "^(\\s*ab*)*$";
```

Comment: btw I think you understand that regex is much more slowly than simple parsing of string in the loop

Comment: ...and a school bus is much slower than a Ferrari, but it gets across the Bay Bridge just as quickly during rush hour.  Please stop repeating these hysterical warnings about how slow regexes are.

Answer (score 0):

If I've gotten your question right, the fault is in the expression. If you always want a white space in the beginning you should use ^(\s+) and not ^(\s*) as * can be 0 occurrences while + mean at least one.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that `findWithinHorizon` method in Scanner is for *finding the next occurrence of a pattern constructed from the specified string* and NOT for matching the whole input. If you write a regex that matched whole input then it will just return the input text **as is** (as per VMykyt's answer here). But that is not you want as I understand.

So you need to make a separate call to [String#matches](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/~cupi2/sitio/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method to make sure there is nothing but spaces in front of your text and if it matches then just find all `ab` ocurrances.

Consider this minor change in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   matchIt("ab abab  ab");
   matchIt("c ab");
   matchIt("cab");
}

private static void matchIt(String str) {
   final String expression = "ab";
   System.out.println("Input: [" + str + ']');
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);

   if(str.matches("^\\s*ab.*$")) {
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {
         String next = scanner.findWithinHorizon(expression, 0);
         if (next == null) {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
            break;
         }
         else {
            System.out.println(next);
         }
      }
   }
   else
      System.out.println("FAIL");
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Input: [ab abab  ab]
ab
ab
ab
ab
===========================
Input: [c ab]
FAIL
===========================
Input: [cab]
FAIL
===========================
```